# IF/THEN/ELSE issue

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to integrate a Money Flow Index in a strategy. The error concerns a If/Then/Else.

```
    mf_index = input(14, "Money Flow Index Length", type=input.integer)
    mf_oversold = input(20, "MFI Oversold Level (%)", type=input.float)
    mf_overbought = input(80, "MFI Overbought Level (%)", type=input.float)

    // Define MFI
    tp = (high + low + close) / 3
    mf_raw = tp * volume
    //next 2 lines is the problem
    posM = sum(if mf_raw > nz(mf_raw[1]) then (mf_raw - 0) else 0, mf_index)
    negM = sum(if mf_raw < nz(mf_raw[1]) then (-mf_raw + 0) else 0, mf_index)
    mf_ratio = posM / negM
    mfi = 100 - 100 / (1 + mf_ratio
```

How does it need to be fixed?

I tried switching the then by ? and else by : but it gives me a syntax error expecting end of line without continuation

Comment: What is your specific problem? See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

no need for the 'if' when using the ternary operator, this compiles fine now after updating those two lines. Also in version 5 it's `math.sum`

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
mf_index = input.int(14, "Money Flow Index Length")
mf_oversold = input.float(20, "MFI Oversold Level (%)")
mf_overbought = input.float(80, "MFI Overbought Level (%)")

    // Define MFI
tp = (high + low + close) / 3
mf_raw = tp * volume
posM = math.sum(mf_raw > nz(mf_raw[1]) ? (mf_raw - 0) : 0, mf_index)
negM = math.sum(mf_raw < nz(mf_raw[1]) ? (-mf_raw + 0) : 0, mf_index)
mf_ratio = posM / negM
mfi = 100 - 100 / (1 + mf_ratio)
```